# Curse(s) on Gayatri

Tags: vedas, vedic-gods, vedic-rituals

In some [sandhyavandan books](http://gitapressbookshop.in/nitya-karm-puja-prakash.html), there is a procedure known as Gayatri shrapvimochan (गायत्री श्रप्विमोचन or [Gayatri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gayatri) curse removal) and it has the following 4 curse removal steps:

> 1. [Brahma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahma) Shrapvimochan (ब्रह्मा श्रप्विमोचन)
> 2. [Vashistha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vashistha) Shrapvimochan (वशिष्ठ श्रप्विमोचन)
> 3. [Vishwamitra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishvamitra) Shrapvimochan ( विश्वामित्र श्रप्विमोचन)
> 4. [Shukra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shukra)  Shrapvimochan (शुक्र  श्रप्विमोचन)

This means that Gayatri was cursed by 4 Brahmarishis (which includes Rishi Vishwamitra).

Is there any scriptural reference to this curse story and validation for this practice? And is it compulsory to do Gayatri shrapvimochan before performing Gayatri japa in sandhyavandana.

Since sandhyavandana is different for all 3 varnas, is it required for Kshatriyas and Vaishyas to perform this gayatri curse removal?

**Note**: Kshatriyas use Trishubh (त्रिश्टुभ) i.e., *[Rig-veda](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/) I, 35, 2* and Vaishyas use Jagati (जगति) i.e., *Rig-veda I, 35, 9* instead of [Gayatri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gayatri_Mantra), in their sandhyavandana. (Source: [The Grihya Sutras](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe29/sbe29035.htm))

Comment: Gayatri Shrapa Vimochana mantras aren't part of my Sandhyavandanam at least.  But I found this forum post which has some information about it: http://www.indiadivine.org/content/topic/1331617-curses-on-gayatri-devi/ Apparently it's only done as part of Tantric Gayatri Upasana associated with the Shakta Tantras, not the standard Vedic Gayatri Upasana that's part of the Sandhyavandanam that most people do.

Comment: The forum post also says "The immidiate context here being seers vas'istA and vis'vAmitrA once wanted the powers of srustI,sthithi and layA/samhArA and despite aeons of tapas, they could not obtain it and thus they cursed gAyatrI devI by way of a KeelanA.Lord BrahmA is said to have cursed the Mother, when he fell into the trap of incestual thoughts against sarasvatI and married Her(some say even gAyatrI)"

Comment: I used to do it(curse removal) earlier but now I follow pure Vedic sandhya procedure. I asked this question so that I could authenticate or discard the practice of curse removal. So there are no authentic scriptural refrences in support of curses??

Comment: Well, that forum post refers to this chapter of the Devi Bhagavatam which describes the Tantric Gayatri Upasana: http://sacred-texts.com/hin/db/bk11ch16.htm "Next for the freedom of the curse of Gâyatrî, do the things properly. Brahmâ gave a curse to Gâyatrî; Vis’vâmitra gave a curse to Her and Vas’istha also cursed Her. These are the three curses; they are removed in due order by recollecting Brahmâ, Vis’vâmitra and Vas’istha."  But I'm not sure what scripture describes the story of the curses.  I'm guessing it may be described in the Shakta Agamas.

Comment: Anga ,Pada and Akshra Nysasas are not Vedic requirements.So are the Gayatri Shapa Vimochana Mantras.They are mentioned in the Devi Bhagawatam.It is said that one is supposed use these mantras ONLY after being guided by Guru.They should NEVER be used on one's own.It is however said that the Gayatri mantra is ineffective without the use of the Shapa Vimochana mantras.So quite a tricky situation.One should do as guided by his Guru.See this image:http://imgur.com/wsfGZDN

Comment: if doing separate anushthana then its needed if done as part of sandhya then exempt from shapavimochana